# Is there a standard installation location for scripts?

Tags: python, scripts, nodejs

I'm deploying a bunch of python scripts to my build, test and soon production server. It can be nodejs or any other thing I want to run under nginx so the location should be generic rather than specific to the type of script.

The files deployed are coming from the the build server artifacts and all versions (build, test and maybe also production) should reside on the same server so using a default folder is not an option as the builds would overwrite each other. The intention is to keep a complete installation contained in one folder per build no matter what type of script it is.

Folder could look something like this:

```
/usr
    /local 
        /build
            /www
            /python
            /nodejs
        /test
            /www
            /python
            /nodejs
```

Is there a preferred location on linux where the root of each build installation should reside?

I have seen `/usr/local` mentioned but am not sure it is the one to use.

Comment: Standard or prefered location? Well, generally speaking, there is no standard installation location for scripts.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Sure there is. Commands (whether it's compiled binaries, perl scripts, python scripts, shell scripts, etc) go in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc.

Comment: @geirha scripts != binaries; `whois perl` != `whois python`; shell scripts can be found in many places... So, what's the standard?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu A lot of the commands in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` (in Ubuntu) are scripts. Commands can be written in whatever language you like, more or less, including scripting languages. Try running `file /usr/bin/* | grep script`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In unix and unix-like systems, you spread the files around the system based on what type of file it is. Executables go in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`, libraries go in `/usr/lib` etc.

Your project sounds more like the "Windows" way; putting all files in one directory. The [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) prefers `/opt` for such schemes.

E.g. `/opt/yourproject_prod/`, `/opt/yourproject_test/`

Comment: Super. The FHS wiki was great. I'm a "forced by employer" Windows guy so that's probably where it's coming from but I knew there must be some best practices somewhere.